# In Powershell, how do you format a folder directory to be a word or sentence rather than the whole directory name?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Say that I have a folder path:
    \myServer\myFolder
Say I want to send someone an email with that path but I want it to be read as "Link to folder". How would I go about renaming the path but keeping it's link?

Comment: What? Is this about PowerShell or about putting links into emails?

Comment: Well, you can email through PowerShell using Send-MailMessage, and I want to add that path in the body but as a sentence.

Comment: Please explain in a clear way what you want to achieve, what you have tried and how it did not work as expected. Does the email part have anything to do with the problem? If not, don't mention it and make a simplified, abstract example - otherwise it just confuses people.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with html:

`<a href="\\server\folder">Link to Folder</a>`

If you send your mails via powershell use the `-bodyashtml` parameter of `Send-Mailmessage` instead of `-body`

Answer (score 0):

Use the replace function:

$Folder="\server\folder"
$Folder=$Folder.Replace('\server\folder','\server\folder')